# Initilizing 2D array class in c++ and passing it to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've created a function to calculate a 3x3 determinant. This is its prototype:

```
double threeDet(array<array<double, 3>, 3> det);
```

I've used class array because it seems safer than traditional arrays.
I wanted to test the function, so I called it:

```
threeDet({ {2, -3, 1}, {2, 0, -1}, {1, 4, 5} });
```

However, it raises an error of "too many initializers"

This has also happened when I changed the function to:

```
double threeDet(double det[][3]);
```

Initializing the array first raises the same error:

```
array<array<double, 3>, 3> det({ {2, -3, 1}, {2, 0, -1}, {1, 4, 5} });
threeDet(det);
```

the only thing that worked is to change the function to the second version, and initialize the array separately:

```
double det[3][3] = { {2, -3, 1}, {2, 0, -1}, {1, 4, 5} };
threeDet(det);
```

I wonder what am I missing, and if there is a way to initialize that I'm missing.

Comment: You seem to be missing a set of outer braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good rule of thumb to follow until one becomes comfortable with braced initialization lists, and how they work: when a `std::array` is involved, double-up the braces:

```
threeDet({{ {{2, -3, 1}}, {{2, 0, -1}}, {{1, 4, 5}} }});
```

A `std::array` is an aggregate object containing one class member: the array itself. So:

- The outer set of braces construct the `std::array`.
- The inner set of braces construct its class member array.

Now, once you get passed that part, you have a pair of braces that construct each value in the array. Well, each such value is also a `std::array`, so you need to drop in another pair of braces to initialize its array class member.